# Maven Not Picking Up Dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have this POM file which has a bunch of dependencies.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mydevgeek</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-template-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>rest-template-service</name>
    <description>Demo Rest Template Service</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

In my source code, I have a class with a bunch of imports

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.RequestEntity; 
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.StringRequestEntity; 

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
```

For some reason, when I run mvn clean install, I get errors when trying to import the httpclient code. All other imports work fine however.

```
package org.apache.commons.httpclient does not exist
```

I have checked my .m2 repository, and I see the httpclient jar there. I have tried removing it and having it downloaded again to make sure it's not corrupt, that did not help.

Suggestions?

Comment: Onces delete that .jar in .m2 folder  re-download it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appache HttpClient v.4.5 does't have such package.

It uses `org.apache.http.`

So you should change you import declarations or use older version of library.

See [here](http://blog.teamextension.com/migrating-from-httpclient-3-1-to-4-0-34) how to migrate to new version.